# Декартово дерево

Tags: c#, wpf

Стоит задача визуализировать декартово дерево, нашел статью на хабре с кодом, как раз был на c#, но возникла такая проблема, что дерево получается несбалансированное. Код никак не видоизменял, единственное добавил функцию которая выводит дерево на экран. Ключи дерева генерирую случайные до 100, приоритеты тоже случайные но там без ограничений. Сам вопрос, что не так с деревом?

```
class Treap
{
    public int x;
    public int y;

    public Treap Left;
    public Treap Right;

    public Treap(int x, int y, Treap left = null, Treap right = null)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.Left = left;
        this.Right = right;
    }

    public static Treap Merge(Treap L, Treap R)
    {
        if (L == null) return R;
        if (R == null) return L;

        if (L.y > R.y)
        {
            var newR = Merge(L.Right, R);
            return new Treap(L.x, L.y, L.Left, newR);
        }
        else
        {
            var newL = Merge(L, R.Left);
            return new Treap(R.x, R.y, newL, R.Right);
        }
    }
    public void Split(int x, out Treap L, out Treap R)
    {
        Treap newTree = null;
        if (this.x <= x)
        {
            if (Right == null)
                R = null;
            else
                Right.Split(x, out newTree, out R);
            L = new Treap(this.x, y, Left, newTree);
        }
        else
        {
            if (Left == null)
                L = null;
            else
                Left.Split(x, out L, out newTree);
            R = new Treap(this.x, y, newTree, Right);
        }
    }
    public Treap Add(int x)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        Treap l, r;
        Split(x, out l, out r);
        Treap m = new Treap(x, rand.Next());
        return Merge(Merge(l, m), r);
    }
    public Treap Remove(int x)
    {
        Treap l, m, r;
        Split(x - 1, out l, out r);
        r.Split(x, out m, out r);
        return Merge(l, r);
    }
    static public void Draw_Tree(Treap root, ref Canvas canvas, int lvl, int width, int section_top, int index)
    {
        if(root == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            int count_of_space = (int)Math.Pow(2, (double)lvl) + 1;
            int section_left = (int)width / count_of_space;
            Ellipse ellipse = new Ellipse();
            ellipse.Height = 20;
            ellipse.Width = 20;
            ellipse.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
            Label label = new Label();
            label.Content = root.x;
            Grid grid = new Grid();
            grid.Children.Add(ellipse);
            grid.Children.Add(label);
            Canvas.SetLeft(grid, section_left * (index - ((int)Math.Pow(2, (double)lvl) - 1) + 1));
            Canvas.SetTop(grid, section_top * (lvl + 1));
            canvas.Children.Add(grid);
            Treap.Draw_Tree(root.Left, ref canvas, lvl + 1, width, section_top, index * 2 + 1);
            Treap.Draw_Tree(root.Right, ref canvas, lvl + 1, width, section_top, index * 2 + 2);
        }
    }
}
```

Вот такое дерево получается на 10 элементов.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А если Random создавать нормально, а не так?

Comment: Нда, кислота... Я помню когда полное (complete) дерево пытался отрисовывать знатно поотлаживался и почеркал листов, прежде чем удалось нормально сделать. А ссылку на статью не хотите привести, м?

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/101818/ вот сама статья. Не совсем понял что не так с рандомом?

Comment: `Random rand = new Random();` вынесите в поле класса из метода и инициализируйте в конструкторе 1 раз.

Comment: @aepot ну я так сделал, но все равно проблема в том что дерево не сбалансированно осталась

Comment: @Stik3r а я и не говорил, что оно поможет, вы спросили `что не так с рандомом?`, я ответил. :)